# How can I make the space between the items of the nav bar be the same between each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav

I'm trying to make the space between the items of the navbar be the same between each other. Sounds like something simple but I haven't managed to do it. I would really appreciate some help with this. Here's the HTML and the CSS. Here's the relevant code:[Here's a photo of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p7z5.jpg)

HTML:

```
<nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tweets.html">Why programming? <a></li>
                    <li><a href="goals.html">Aspirations and goals<a></li>
                    <li><a href="my_projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="books.html">Favourite books</a></li>
                    <li><a href="interests.html">Interests</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    right: -90px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    bottom:10px;
    align-items:flex-end;
    font-size: 20 px;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
    padding-left:50px;
    padding-right: 50px;}
```

[image]

Comment: in CSS you are targeting the nav element, but the nav element is not the immediate parent of your links (list elements).

Answer (score 0):

Can't exactly test it with just the code provided but try setting your margins in css, they should control your distance. You may want to tinker with margin-left and margin-right

`justify-content: space-evenly;  /* Distribute items evenly Items have equal space around them */` May also be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

As because you are using **flex-box**, so you can use justify content space between, space around  or space evenly, or you can use margin left, right property

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content : space-between / space-evenly  / space-around 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem after I tested it with the code above and fixed it just by adding a few things.  This works with your existing css code still being used!!

You not using the **li** or **ul** class in your **css** which is a big part of what your trying to do. You can add **li a** to have **padding-left: 4px;** and **padding-right: 4px;** and **display: flex;** - Also by making **ul** **list-style-type: none;** than your list won't have a list icon next to it.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content : space-between or space-evenly (as per design)
    width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex box on `ul` as:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="tweets.html">Why programming? </a></li>
    <li><a href="goals.html">Aspirations and goals</a></li>
    <li><a href="my_projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="books.html">Favourite books</a></li>
    <li><a href="interests.html">Interests</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```